# ActiveMQ Artemis failing to deliver large messages

Tags: activemq-artemis

We are using ActiveMQ Artemis as a message broker in a Kubernetes environment. So far it works for small messages, but when sending larger messages, which are roughly between 150k and 200k, the messages are not delivered. The messages are being paged to disk as we see them in the `large-messages` directory, but they are not being redelivered after being paged.

In case this makes a difference, on the receiving client side, we are using the JavaScript Rhea package, and the sending client is a C++ app using QPid Proton.

We have scoured the internet and have not found any real solutions to this. We're hoping a solution is just a matter of a configuration setting somewhere. Does anyone have any suggestions to try?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the broker log?

Comment: @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino No, there are no errors in the broker log.

Comment: Did you try using something other than Rhea for the receiver, I'd not be surprised if that client is not ideal for large message consumption

Comment: @TimBish Good call - the issue was a bug in Rhea.